# What is the Pytorch sub for this tensor flow code?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

In converting this line of code to Pytorch from Tensor Flow, I am having trouble

```
datagen =  ImageDataGenerator(
  shear_range=0.2,
  zoom_range=0.2,
)
def read_img(filename, size, path):
    img = image.load_img(os.path.join(path, filename), target_size=size)
    #convert image to array
    img = img_to_array(img) / 255
    return img
```

and then

```
corona_df = final_train_data[final_train_data['Label_2_Virus_category'] == 'COVID-19']
with_corona_augmented = []

#create a function for augmentation
def augment(name):
    img = read_img(name, (255,255), train_img_dir)
    i = 0
    for batch in tqdm(datagen.flow(tf.expand_dims(img, 0), batch_size=32)):
        with_corona_augmented.append(tf.squeeze(batch).numpy())
        if i == 20:
            break
        i =i+1

#apply the function
corona_df['X_ray_image_name'].apply(augment)
```

I tried doing

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(255*255)
                               ])
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(os.path.join(train_dir,corona_df),transform = transform,batch_size =32)
def read_img(path):
    img  = train_loader()
    img = np.asarray(img,dtype='int32')
    img = img/255
    return img
```

I tried continuing but got soo confused by the errors.
I welcome any feedback. Tell me If i miss something
Even a small advice would work, thanks !

Comment: Can you write your errors that you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom dataset to read the images. If you have a directory full of images you can use ImageFolder default dataset. Otherwise if you have different folder placement you can write your own custom dataset class. You can look to [this link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) for custom datasets. What dataloader does is, it automatically gets the data from your dataset and read the images according to your dataset `__getitem__` function and apply transformation. So you don't need anything fancy to apply augmentation.

```
transform = transforms.Compose([ transforms.RandomAffine(20,shear=20,scale=(-0.2,0.2)),
                                 transforms.Resize(255*255)
                               ])

dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(train_img_dir, transform=transform)
loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset,batch_size =32,shuffle=True)

for batch in loader:
    output = model(batch)
```

Comment: Thnx foe the info. But what I am trouble finding is : getting image of only one that is in a list not the whole from the folder. I . I have a list. Id i put the list in os.path.join it gives error as it requires str* format and not series

Comment: Actually this is what I mean by custom dataset. In custom dataset you should create a list which contains all image names. Then using each path you should read the image. You didn't put your error so I cannot know what your error is. If you have pandas series you can convert it to series.values.tolist() so you get only list of strings.